# Failure of Web Server bridge

Tags: weblogic

estoy trabajando con una aplicación y desde mi local en entorno W10 apuntando a una BBDD de oracle 18.3 me ejecuta bien, como servidor de aplicaciones en mi eclipse Neon 4.6.2 uso Tomcat 7.0. El problema es que subo ese código a una máquina remota que tiene como servidor de aplicaciones oracle weblogic no sé si versión 10 ,11 o 12 y al intentar realizar la misma acción me da el siguiente error (en el navegador):
Failure of Web Server bridge:
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 20 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.

Además si miro el log veo que aparece el error siguiente (he sustituido la clase en cuestion por miClase y el metodo en cuestion por miMetodo)

```
[17/04/2019][13:05:40,509] ERROR miClase.miMetodo(245): Error al crear ...!
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:507)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:486)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:382)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:313)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:580)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.write(CharsetChunkOutput.java:221)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:138)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(IOUtils.java:1010)
        at es.buildingcenter.services.controller.miClase.miMetodo(miClase.java:243)
        at es.buildingcenter.services.controller.miClase$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7847ad86.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at es.buildingcenter.services.aspect.ControllerAspect.aroundControllerExecution(ControllerAspect.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
        at es.buildingcenter.services.controller.miClase$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1e290cb.miMetodo(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
[17/04/2019][13:05:40,604] INFO  ControllerAspect.aroundControllerExecution(174): Resultado: null
```